# Scons - How Can I Detect When a File is Pulled from Cache?

Tags: caching, builder, scons

I have an issue in which I need some code to run as a result of a command builder:

`node = env.Command (target, dependencies, function)`

In this case, function will run if the target is out of date, which is what I want, but if the target is in the cache, function doesn't run.  What I'd like is to run a different function if the target is pulled from cache.

I tried:

`env.AddPostAction(node, function2)`

but that function doesn't get called either.

Any ideas?  Thanks.

Comment: what exactly are you trying to achieve - why'd you want to do something different if the file came from cache? Doesn't that rather destroy the point of having a cache in the first place?

Comment: I'm doing the above for 3 files, and if any is out of date I will launch an app to rebuild. The app will rebuild any or all of these 3 files and I want the app to run once only (performance reasons). The 'function' sets a bit mask per file; the 'function2' is common to all 3 files and decides if the app needs to be run and with what args.  But 'function2' can't tell if it was bypassed because a file is in the cache.

Comment: so you get from the above node1, node2, node3 and you have an app which you then run to generate node1a, node2a, node3a? But you don't want it to run on node2, why not exactly? I don't see how node2a can be fetched from anywhere in that case

Comment: 'function2' refers to the function named in the AddPostAction line. In my original description I didn't want to muddy the waters describing the 3 files, so I gave the example of just one file and 2 functions. There would be a node1, node2, node3, and 3 post action functions which we can call functionPA1, functionPA2, functionPA3.

Comment: Yes, but I'm trying to find out what you want to build, not how you want to do it in SCons. So what are your inputs and outputs?

Comment: I want to build 3 xml files. The input is a database, and we have a set of timestamped files that correspond to different parts of the database.  Those files are listed as our dependencies.  They can all be built individually, but it saves a lot of time if we run our java app once to build whichever of the 3 needs to be rebuilt.

Comment: I managed to fix the issue by adding another Command and a new function to see if the java app needs to be run, and then making that Command dependent on the 3 nodes from the 3 XML Commands.  But it would be nice to know when the cache satisfied a Command.

Answer (score 0):

Afaik, scons will not know how it will satisfy the demand while executing your code. It makes that decision after completing the 1st pass. So, even if you could tell, I don't believe you could act on it within your code.

An easy, obvious way is to parse the scons output for 'Retrieved ... File name'.

And of course, the problem suggests the dependencies are set up badly, and it looks like you fixed that.